# How to pass value to Context Provider in TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-context

I am trying to convert my react scripts to typescript and having issues defining the types:

```
export const inputListContext = createContext<null>(null)

import {MyEnum} from "../ts-api-script";


type checkBoxParams = {
    myEnum: any
    name: any
}


export const Options = () => {

const [greenVals, setGreenVals] = useState(Set<MyEnum>);
const [redVals, setRedVals] = useState(Set<MyEnum>);

const greenValue = {greenVals, setGreenVals};
const redValue = {redVals, setRedVals};


return (
  <inputListContext.Provider value={{greenValue, redValue}}>
    <Checkbox myEnum={FirmStatusEnum.Op} name={"Option 1"}</Checkbox>
 </inputListContext.Provider>

)
}
```

All I am trying to do is pass the red and green objects as values to my context provider. The issue is coming from typescript.

```
ERROR:
Type '{ greenValue: any; redValue: { redVals: { new (values?: readonly FirmStatusEnum[] | null | undefined): Set<MyEnum>; new (iterable?: Iterable<MyEnum> | null | undefined): Set<...>; readonly prototype: Set<...>; readonly [Symbol.species]: SetConstructor; }; setRedVals: React.Dispatch<...>; }; }' is not assignable to type 'null'
```

What are the steps I need to take to declare my types properly and rectify this?

Comment: Typescript is complaining about you creating and defining your context to be null type, and you are trying to pass values to it. the Dynamic type of createContext<T> needs to be updated to something not null - `createContext<null>(null)` - try setting it to any and work back from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I think using `Set<MyEnum>` for `useState` initialization does not seem to be ok.
So you can write the `Options` component like this:

```
function Options() {
    const [greenVals, setGreenVals] = useState(new Set<MyEnum>());
    const [redVals, setRedVals] = useState(new Set<MyEnum>());

    const greenValue = { greenVals, setGreenVals };
    const redValue = { redVals, setRedVals };

    return (
        <inputListContext.Provider
            value={{
                redValue,
                greenValue,
            }}
        >
            {/* whatever you want to pass */}
        </inputListContext.Provider>
    );
}
```

Then let's get to `inputListContext`. You should declare an interface outside of your `Options` component representing the `inputListContext` type, which based on what you mentioned in the question is something like this:

```
interface inputListContextType {
    greenValue: { greenVals: Set<MyEnum>, setGreenVals: Dispatch<SetStateAction<Set<MyEnum>>> };
    redValue: { redVals: Set<MyEnum>, setRedVals: Dispatch<SetStateAction<Set<MyEnum>>> };

}
```

And Next you create `inputListContext` not with `null` type and `null` initial value.

```
const inputListContext = createContext<inputListContextType>({
    greenValue: { greenVals: new Set<MyEnum>(), setGreenVals: () => { } },
    redValue: { redVals: new Set<MyEnum>(), setRedVals: () => { } },
});
```