# Writing a TypeScript Interface for React Context, how to describe the interface/ different types to be passed as values?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-context

I am trying to write a React Context for my application

This is a follow up from my previous question:

[How to pass value to Context Provider in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74181632/how-to-pass-value-to-context-provider-in-typescript/74182830#74182830)

I would please like some help describing different value types to be passed through the provider.

*Overview:*

I am currently trying to construct a context provider that can be used across the scope of my application in TypeScript.

It contains some useState hooks and and an asynchronous function to be passed through as values the provider to all the child components.

**ResultConextProvider.tsx**

```
export const ResultContextProvider = () => {

    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState<boolean>(false)


    const [greenStatus, setGreenStatus] =
        useState(new Set<MyEnum>());

    const [redStatus, setRedStatus] =
        useState(new Set<MyEnum>());

    const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState<string>('')

   // objects to be passed values 
    const greenValue = {greenStatus, setGreenStatus};
    const redValue = {redStatus, setRedStatus};
    const searchValue = {searchTerm, setSearchTerm};


  // api function coming from tested API spec (external)
    const getResults = async () => {
        setIsLoading(true)
        myAPI.myGet(greenStatus, redStatus).then((result) => {
            setResults(result.data);
        })
        setIsLoading(false)
    }

    return (
        <ResultContext.Provider value={{getResults, greenValue, redValue, searchValue}}>
       {children}
      </ResultContext.Provider>
}

export const useResultContext = () => useContext(ResultContext);
```

As you can see above, I would like to pass the getResults function, my greenValues, redValus and searchValues to all my child components, the Provider implentation will look something like this:

**index.tsx**

```
import { ResultContextProvider } from "./contexts/ResultContextProvider";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(
  document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement
);
root.render(
   <ResultContextProvider
     <Router>
       <App />
    </Router>
   </ResultContextProvider>
);
```

When it comes to writing the interface, I am struggling to understand what needs to be represented prior to my component.

So far my interface looks something like this:

**ResultConextProvider.tsx**

```
interface ContextParametersType {
    greenValue: { greenStatus: Set<MyEnum>, setGreenStatus: 
          Dispatch<SetStateAction<Set<MyEnum>>> };
    redValue: { redStatus: Set<MyEnum>, setRedStatus: 
          Dispatch<SetStateAction<Set<MyEnum>>> };
    
    ///INCORRECT //
    // searchValue: {searchTerm: <string>(''), setSearchTerm: 
          Dispatch<SetStateAction<string> };

    ///UNSURE
    // getResults : {

    // What to write as interface for getResults

    // }

}
```

I have worked out what needs to be declared for my greenValue and redValue, based on the answer to my previous question however struggling to fill out the rest of the interface specification

1. The Search Term:

   ///INCORRECT //
   // searchValue: {searchTerm: (''), setSearchTerm:
   Dispatch<SetStateAction };

I have tried to follow the pattern of the Enum state, particularly in declaring the state as type string and rerferecning the Dispatch<SetStateAction as the same type to change the state however this produces error

2. getResults

This is an asynchronous function with an Axios function inside, to be truthful i do not know where to begin within this one.

My confusion on these two steps persists when creating the ResultContext

```
const ResultContext = createContext<ContextParametersType>({
    greenValue: {
        greenStatus: new Set<FirmStatusEnum>(), setGreenStatus: () => {
        }
    },
    redValue: {
        redStatus: new Set<FirmStatusEnum>(), setRedStatus: () => {
        }
    },

    // searchValue: {
    //     searchTerm: <string>(''), setSearchTerm: () => {
    //     }
    // },

   getResults() 

   // Not Sure how to initalsie this?
   
});
```

Does this make sense? Am I understanding the issues here correctly?

I would really like some help in understanding how to configure the context interfaces for this.

It is essentially a typescript adaptation of this tutorial

[Here:](https://youtu.be/NDbruK1fzG8?t=2278)

Thanks, please let me know if I need to provide clarity